# Sorting in localeCompare in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, collation

I am working on a Javascript code as shown below:

```js
let arr = [
  '1 Hello',
  '2 Hello',
  '3 Hello',
  '4 Hello',
  ';1',
  'z',
  '%1',
  '110 Hello',
  '100 Hello',
  'a',
  'Z',
  '00',
  '21 Hello',
  '9  Hello',
  '13 Hello',
  '10000 Hello',
  '0 Hello',
  'A'
  ];


arr.sort( (a, b) => {
  return a.localeCompare(b, 'en', {
    numeric: true
  })
} ).forEach( ml => { console.log(ml) });
```

**The above Javascript is printing the following o/p:**

```
;1
%1
00
0 Hello
1 Hello
2 Hello
3 Hello
4 Hello
9  Hello
13 Hello
21 Hello
100 Hello
110 Hello
10000 Hello
a
A
z
Z
=> undefined
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering why in the o/p `;1` is coming before `%1` and how other strings are getting sorted here?

Comment: I'd imagine it's just alphabetical/Unicode code point order. By specifying `numeric: true`, `"1" < "2" , "10"`, as opposed to a default alphabetical string sort, where `"1"  < "10" < "2"`.

Comment: It's called [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order). I guess `;` comes before `%` like `a` comes before `z`. Alternating cases is interesting too. Here's some related reading: https://www.sitepoint.com/sophisticated-sorting-in-javascript/

Comment: @TylerRoper No, by codepoints `%` comes first (and then digits), then `;`.

Comment: @melpomene You're absolutely right.

Comment: Because they do treat punctuation marks separately by default. You can avoid it by using the `ignorePunctuation` option.

Comment: Also, why `z` came after `A` ?

Comment: @melpomene What are codepoints ? Do you mean to say ASCII table ?

Comment: @john Unicode codepoints look like `U+0420` or `U+205AC`. I had suggested that perhaps that was the sort order in my original comment (it's the default sort order for `Array.sort` without a function), however melpomene corrected me - it is *not* sorting by codepoints. I'm not familiar enough with the sorting prioritization of `localeCompare` to give an answer to your question though.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point

Answer (score 2):

tldr; Browser specific implementation. Recently "standardized".
In my answer I suppose that the question is not about the `.sort()` array method in JS, but about outputs of the `.localeCompare()` string method. If we go to MDN description of the method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare we can find the definition:

> The localeCompare() method returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order.

As well as a link to specification: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.localecompare . This specification has this excerpt:

> When the localeCompare method is called with argument *that*, it returns a Number other than *NaN* that represents the result of a locale-sensitive String comparison of the this value (converted to a String) with *that* (converted to a String). The two Strings are *S* and *That*. **The two Strings are compared in an implementation-defined fashion.** The result is intended to order String values in the sort order specified by a host default locale...

You can find a "bug" report for Chromium "***localeCompare implementation differs from other browsers***": https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=459 , - with examples like:

```
in v8 version 1.3.13.5, i get these results for the final sort:
A,R,Z,a,q,z,ä,æ

safari produces:
A,a,ä,æ,q,R,Z,z

firefox produces:
a,A,ä,æ,q,R,z,Z
```

and [one of the answers](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=459#c23):

> Marking as feature request as the current implementation does not violate the spec.

Currently AFAIK for comparison i18n `Intl API` specification is used. You can find more about the comparison rules in the specification: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/2.0/#collator-objects . This document also has this note on the comparison options:

> Unicode Technical Standard 35 describes ten locale extension keys that are relevant to collation: "co" for collator usage and specializations, "ka" for alternate handling, "kb" for backward second level weight, "kc" for case level, "kn" for numeric, "kh" for hiragana quaternary, "kk" for normalization, "kf" for case first, "kr" for reordering, "ks" for collation strength, and "vt" for variable top.

So you can tweak the output to the certain levels. I hope this is helpful, thanks :)